# write my tree object to a file in java?

Tags: java, file

i want to write an object of my class to a file and use it later 
how should i do?
for example i want to write t4 to file:

```
   BinaryTree t1 = new BinaryTree( 1 );
        BinaryTree t3 = new BinaryTree( 3 );
        BinaryTree t5 = new BinaryTree( 5 );
        BinaryTree t7 = new BinaryTree( 7 );
        BinaryTree t2 = new BinaryTree( );
        BinaryTree t4 = new BinaryTree( );
        BinaryTree t6 = new BinaryTree( );
        BinaryTree t8 = new BinaryTree( );
        BinaryTree t9 = new BinaryTree( );

        t2.merge( 2, t1, t3 );
        t6.merge( 6, t5, t7 );
        t4.merge(4, t2, t6);
```

please say how write and how read that file
(using java neatbeans)
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your implement the Serializable interface.  Then you could just save the object using the following:

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream( "tree.bin" );
OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream( file );
ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream( buffer );

output.writeObject(tree);
```

To load from file you would then use the following:

```
InputStream file = new FileInputStream( "quarks.ser" );
InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream( file );
ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream ( buffer );

BinaryTree tree = (BinaryTree)input.readObject();
```

For more information look at the following [link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=57)

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/). have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html